# Answer or comment?

Tags: support

In cases like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254075/calculating-the-number-of-terms-in-arithmetic-sequence), should it be answered or just finish it off in comments? I was doubtful, nearly deleted my answer (twice) and undeleted it later!

Also, should questions like this (very basics, which may have been asked in many different ways already) be answered or just directed to the answer in comments?

(I did see [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10589/do-hints-belong-in-answers-or-comments), but my question is whether such questions should even be answered!)

Comment: Personally, I very much dislike the use of "spoilers."

Comment: @quid, I do, too, (using it for the first time) but prefer to it than to giving away the answer just like that! I took the hint from linked meta post in my question!

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I am still debating with myself if I should comment there too.

Comment: @quid, Are there any proper guideline where points in linked post and this question (and similar ones - differentiating comments and answers, and what deserves to be a comment and what should/can be an answer etc) are brought together?

Comment: This is a tricky issue as opinions are mixed. The SE guideline would be roughly:  comments are intended for transient information only. Something of lasting relevance should be an edit, an answer, or a new question. In practice it is a bit more fuzzy and some will disagree altogether, but still the point is that relevant information should rather not be in comments. Note for example one cannot even search for content in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking, there are three ways to 'finish' a question post:

- answer
- mark as duplicate
- close/on-hold as unsuitable (and perhaps eventually delete)

If you do not think the last should happen and the second is not an option either, then you should create an answer-post. If you think the last should happen, then you rather should not  answer in comments either.

Comment: Helps! Thank you!